# Getting error "Cannot get Role Manager with name aspnetsqlroleprovider", even without using this provider

Tags: claims-based-auth, role-provider

I'm working on a large SharePoint farm that use claims authentication.

We are using both Integrated authentication, and a custom provider called "myprovider".

However, I'm getting random error event (1-3 per day):

> Cannot get Role Manager with name aspnetsqlroleprovider. The role manager for this process was not properly configured. You must configure the role manager in the .config file for every SharePoint process.

We have properly set the role provider and the membership provider wherever it's required (or at least we think we did it everywhere):

- in all web.config of web applications, the providers has been set up
- in the central administration, the providers are set at the authentication provider screen
- in the security token service, the providers have been set up
- the superreader/superuser accounts are properly set up, with the claims prefix and the correct providers.

How can I find what is responsible of this event?

If it can help, the full event entry is :

```
<Event xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/win/2004/08/events/event">
    <System>
        <Provider Name="Microsoft-SharePoint Products-SharePoint Foundation" Guid="{6FB7E0CD-52E7-47DD-997A-241563931FC2}" /> 
        <EventID>6143</EventID> 
        <Version>14</Version> 
        <Level>1</Level> 
        <Task>7</Task> 
        <Opcode>0</Opcode> 
        <Keywords>0x4000000000000000</Keywords> 
        <TimeCreated SystemTime="2012-10-30T10:02:15.884822500Z" /> 
        <EventRecordID>451242</EventRecordID> 
        <Correlation ActivityID="{999A11D3-7F90-4D1F-AF9D-E28F99092F5B}" /> 
        <Execution ProcessID="5744" ThreadID="10636" /> 
        <Channel>Application</Channel> 
        <Computer>myserver.corp.int</Computer> 
        <Security UserID="S-1-5-21-1234567890-1263408776-2012955550-32865" /> 
    </System>
    <EventData>
        <Data Name="string0">Cannot get Role Manager with name aspnetsqlroleprovider. The role manager for this process was not properly configured. You must configure the role manager in the .config file for every SharePoint process.</Data> 
    </EventData>
</Event>
```

Answer (score 1):

See http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff758656.aspx if you haven't set up the SuperUser and SuperReader accounts. Setting them up exactly per the instructions will resolve it.

Comment: This has been setup since the creation of the web apps. And I'm not sure why this would be related